# Grouping data into ranges

Tags: mysql

I have a query that returns the counts from a database. Sample output of the query:

```
23
14
94
42
23
12
```

The query:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `submissions`
INNER JOIN `events`
ON `submissions`.event_id = `events`.id
WHERE events.user_id IN (
SELECT id
FROM `users`
WHERE users.created_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `events`.id
```

Is there a way to easily take the output and split it into pre-defined ranges of values (0-100, 101-200, etc), indicating the number of rows that fall into a particular range?

Comment: Based on result in op, what is your expected result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a case expression in select clause.

```
SELECT `events`.id , 
case when COUNT(`events`.id) between 0 and 100 then '0 - 100'
when COUNT(`events`.id) between 100 and 200 then '100 - 200'
end as Range
FROM `submissions`
INNER JOIN `events`
ON `submissions`.event_id = `events`.id
WHERE events.user_id IN (
SELECT id
FROM `users`
WHERE users.created_at IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY `events`.id
```

Comment: This worked for me -- I knew about the CASE statement, but wasn't sure how to integrate it with the rest of the query. Thank you kindly!

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional count by leveraging `SUM()` aggregate.

If you need your ranges in columns

```sql
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN n BETWEEN(  0 AND 100) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '0-100',
       SUM(CASE WHEN n BETWEEN(101 AND 200) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) '101-200'
       -- , add other ranges here
  FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(*) n
        FROM submissions s JOIN events e
          ON s.event_id = e.id JOIN users u
          ON e.user_id = u.id
       WHERE u.created_at IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY e.id
  ) q
```

Sample output

```
+-------+---------+
| 0-100 | 101-200 |
+-------+---------+
|     2 |       3 |
+-------+---------+
1 row in set (0.01 sec)
```

If you'd rather have it as a set you can do

```sql
SELECT CONCAT(r.min, '-', r.max) `range`,
       SUM(n BETWEEN r.min AND r.max) count
  FROM (
      SELECT COUNT(*) n
        FROM submissions s JOIN events e
          ON s.event_id = e.id JOIN users u
          ON e.user_id = u.id
       WHERE u.created_at IS NOT NULL
       GROUP BY e.id
  ) q CROSS JOIN (
      SELECT 0 min, 100 max
      UNION ALL
      SELECT 101, 200
      -- add other ranges here
  ) r
 GROUP BY r.min, r.max
```

Sample output

```
+---------+-------+
| range   | count |
+---------+-------+
| 0-100   |     2 |
| 101-200 |     3 |
+---------+-------+
2 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```